# Order by difference between 2 columns of

Tags: symfony1, propel

I have a mysql query to oreder by using difference of two fields of same table

```
SELECT *
FROM postings
ORDER BY vote_up - vote_down;
```

its working

How i write this query using propel criteria,

I write like this `$criteria->addDescendingOrderByColumn(self::VOTE_UP-self::VOTE_DOWN)`

but it makes errors. Anybody know please help.

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What are the errors? It works with doctrine without a problem: Doctrine::getTable('Model')->
     createQuery('m')->
     orderBy('m.vote_up - m.vote_down DESC')->execute();

Comment: What version of Propel? In ModelCriteria.php, in the function getSelectStatement, you can do `sfContext::getInstance()->getLogger->log($sql)` after the line that says `$sql = BasePeer::createSelectSql($this, $params);` (or something similar if it's different in your version of Propel). That's the easiest way to see what SQL is being generated; obviously take the debug out when you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`$criteria->addDescendingOrderByColumn(self::VOTE_UP.' - '.self::VOTE_DOWN)`